# In Firebase how do we add more fields to a document through flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm not sure how to add an extra field to a firestore document through code. I do not want to create new fields through firebase console, since these field names will be dynamic and be used for searching. EX: if a field does "NOT" exist, add to result. (Since firestore does not allow negation queries.

Comment: The fields which don't exist, when accessed through the document snapshot return null. Are you looking for this kind of behaviour? If you want to create non-existing fields, you can run a transaction with an update. All the other fields will be untouched. It would be really helpful if you perhaps post some code as an example on what you exactly are trying to acheive.

Comment: Firestore has no condition updates. So there's no "add a field if it doesn't exist yet". If you want to update a document, writing the field and leaving other fields untouched, you can use `update` or `set(, { merge:true})`. If you only want to write the field if it doesn't exist yet, you'll need a transaction (which does a read-then-write).

Answer (score 15):

In [Cloud_Firestore#0.14.0](https://pub.dev/packages/cloud_firestore/versions/0.14.0/changelog), there has been many changes.

> "setData/set now supports SetOptions to merge data/fields (previously this accepted a Map)"

Now, for this you need to do it as follows:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('collectionName')
  .doc('docID')
  .set({
  'field': 'value'
},SetOptions(merge: true)).then((value){
  //Do your stuff.
});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
firestore.instance.collection('yourDbCollection').doc('ifYourIdCostumized').update({
            field: newItem
        })
            .then(function () {
                console.log("Document successfully updated!");
            }).catch(function (error) {
                console.error("Error removing document: ", error);

            });
```

Answer (score 2):

`firestore.instance.collection("collectionName").document("documentID").setData({field : value }, merge: true).then((onValue){//your other code}`

This Code will work.
Use setData and use merge: true as shown in the above code snippet.